# Restrict Docker Swarm mode service placement to "not this node"

Tags: docker, docker-stack

I've got a Docker swarm mode setup where the nodes look something like this

- swarm-manager

  - swarm-worker-01
  - swarm-worker-02
  - swarm-worker-for-my-special-application
  - swarm-worker-for-my-special-application-02

`swarm-manager` hosts a reverse proxy, and the worker node host a bunch of more-or-less unrelated small apps (we're a small design agency).

For the most part, these apps are low bandwidth and just hum along without bothering each other. However, we now have a new app (let's call it `special-application`) that wants to be able to deploy to any of the worker nodes (as it's a high-traffic application), but I want to restrict other services besides `special application` from deploying to these nodes.

So, I want something like this:

- swarm-worker-01 (accepts any container)
- swarm-worker-02 (accepts any container)
- swarm-worker-for-my-special-application (accepts only `special application`)
- swarm-worker-for-my-special-application-02 (accepts only `special application`)

One (kind of) solution would be to give the special nodes a label, such as `docker node update --label-add app-constraint=special-application swarm-worker-for-my-special-application`, and then on my special application, deploy with:

```
deploy:
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.labels.app-constraint == special-application
```

and on my other apps:

```
deploy:
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.labels.app-constraint != special-application
```

However, this has two downsides. One is that my `special-application` will only get deployed on the special nodes, not all nodes. The second is that I'll have to go through each of my (dozens of) other services and redeploy with an a constraint.

Basically, I want `special application` to be able to deploy anywhere, whilst having certain workers to only accept deploys from special application, in effect reserving capacity for them.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?